# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning with custom IntersectionObserver hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this custom react hook copied more of less straight from this dev.to article for use of the `IntersecionObserver` in React. [article here](https://dev.to/producthackers/intersection-observer-using-react-49ko)

**The Hook**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"


export const useIntersectionObserver = (options) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)

  const callback = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries
    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting)
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    let currentEl;

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

    if (containerRef && containerRef.current) {
      currentEl = containerRef.current;
      observer.observe(currentEl);
    }

    return () => {
      if (containerRef && containerRef.current) {
        currentEl = containerRef.current;
        observer.unobserve(currentEl);
      }
    }
  }, [containerRef, options])

  return [containerRef, isVisible]
}
```

in my console I have this warning,

> The ref value 'containerRef.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'containerRef.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Can someone please provide a more in-depth explanation as to what exactly this means or point me to a resource? As well as the solution to satisfy the error requirement. From what I can see `containerRef.current` IS referenced inside the `useEffect` cleanup, clearly I do not have a solid understanding of what is actually happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning exists because, in some cases, the `.current` value referenced in the body of an effect will be different from the `.current` value referenced in the cleanup function. In general, if you do

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code that references someRef.current
  return () => {
    // more code that references someRef.current
  };
```

you may well be counting on both such references to reference the same value - but that's not guaranteed, and will sometimes be a source of bugs.

In your code, there is only one line in the code which throws the error, which is this one:

```
return () => {
    if (containerRef && containerRef.current) {
        currentEl = containerRef.current; // <--------
        observer.unobserve(currentEl);
    }
}
```

Which is reasonable - there's no absolute guarantee that your

```
  currentEl = containerRef.current;
  observer.observe(currentEl);
```

in the effect body will be the same element unobserved in the cleanup function.

The fix would be to extract the `.current` value into a variable in the effect body, and reference that variable in the cleanup.

Also note that a ref will always be truthy - no need to test it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentEl = containerRef.current;
    if (!currentEl) return; // no need to attach observer or cleanup

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    observer.observe(currentEl);
    return () => {
        observer.unobserve(currentEl);
    };
  }, [containerRef, options])
```